# Python pack arguments?

Tags: python, arguments, iterable-unpacking

is to possible to "pack" arguments in python? I have the following functions in the library, that I can't change (simplified):

```
def g(a,b=2):
    print a,b

def f(arg):
    g(arg)
```

I can do

```
o={'a':10,'b':20}
g(**o)
10 20
```

but can I/how do I pass this through `f`?

That's what I don't want:

```
f(**o)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'a'

f(o)
{'a': 10, 'b': 20} 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`f` has to accept arbitrary (positional and) keyword arguments:

```
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    g(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you don't want `f` to accept positional arguments, leave out the `*args` part.

Comment: The problem here is, that I cannot change f or g, it's not mine :) Of course I could file a bug.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question in that respect. Then I think you have no other choice than reimplementing `f` or requesting a change in the library.

Comment: As it stands, `f` provides no way to pass a value to `b` in `g`, so you should file a bug